# How to obtain the date of a file which was read through URL connection?

Tags: java, file, url

I would like to know how can I obtain the date of a (XML) file which was read through an URL connection. I am storing this file in a database and I want to update it if the file has changed. For this reason I would like to obtain its date.

Currently I have implemented the code that obtains and parses the file:

```
private PolicyDocument getPolicyFileFromURI(String policyURI){
    //get the QoD-policy document using the URI
    URL url;
    PolicyDocument policy = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(policyURI);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        try {
            XmlOptions options = new XmlOptions();
            policy = PolicyDocument.Factory.parse(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ContextException("Couldn't read qod-policy document at location " + policyURI, e);
        }           
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return policy;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
Date date = new Date(connection.getLastModified());
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is being served up through HTTP, there is no automatic way to check in your code on the client-side what the "generated date" of the file is - but if you control the server that is serving the XML file, you could add HTTP headers to the response that indicate the filesystem modified date of the file.

Comment: The file is from apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\.

Comment: What about java.net.URLConnection, public long getLastModified()?
"Gets the last modified date of the object. Returns 0 if not known." Which object's date is returned, that of the file or of the URLConnection?

Comment: @Peter the Javadoc for URLConnection.getLastModified() state `Returns the value of the last-modified header field.`. This would only apply if you are reading files over HTTP, and it would rely on the server on the other end sending the correct value in the `last-modified` header. If you are reading from the filesystem, just use Files.getLastModifiedTime(path) http://bit.ly/1iuLQzn